# Integrating bit.ly and twilio

Tags: c#, twilio, bit.ly

I'm trying to add shortened bit.ly links to sms sent programmatically using TwilioApi. The code is working, but for some reason the shortened link is being resolved even if nobody clicked it (bit.ly dashboard, 0 clicks).

Is it possible that Twilio or bit.ly check if the link I'm trying to send is scam/fishing/etc?

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

I'm using c#, here an extract of my code:

```
IBitlyService s = new BitlyService("BitlyAccount", "BitlyApiKey");

string url = string.Format("http://myurl.php?idSomething={0}&idSomethingElse={1}", idSomething, idSomethingElse);

if(s.Shorten(url, out shortened) == StatusCode.OK)
{
string smsText = string.Format("Some info and stuff, click this link {0}", shortened);

TwilioRestClient tw = new TwilioRestClient("TwilioSid", "TwilioToken");

Message m = tw.SendMessage(phoneNumberSending, phoneNumberReceiving, smsText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

So I thought it was odd Twilio would be loading up a link before something was sent as it would totally invalidate one time only links.

I built a little POC here where I firstly tried to send a link that had not been previously shortened via Twilio and confirmed Twilio didn't hit it by [sending an SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) with it.

[image]

I then tried to go to bit.ly and paste the link to my application so it would be shortened. That then made a request to my application (which I guess is correct since bit.ly needs to check whether that link is valid in order to minify it)

[image]

So I believe it's bit.ly who's making the request to your application when you minify it to make sure your link is valid. You can be sure of that by running it locally and exposing it via ngrok like I did, or looking at your webserver's logs to see where the request is actually coming from.

A good starting point would be trying to send the URL without it being minified and seeing what happens. You could also try to look for another url shortening service, or roll your own.

Let me know if I can help you with anything else.